# Update Database from Offline

Tags: php, mysql, webserver, localhost

I have just created a web application using PHP Mysql I want to install this system in localserver as well as online webserver. But When Not Net Connection it store in local mysql and auto update or synchronize the online mysql data.

Kinly help me How can Is Possible.. I Have just use this but not working.

```
            <form action ='#' method ='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                            <div class="form-group">

                                        <input type='hidden' class="form-control" value='<?php echo $dbname;?>' name='dbname' required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Upload Photograph </label>
                                        <input type="file" name='backup_file'>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value='Restore' name='submit'>
            </form>


<?php

include_once('conn.php');
// ------------ Upload Process  -------------------------------//
if(isset($_FILES['backup_file']))
{                               
$file = $_FILES ['backup_file'];
$name1 = $file ['name'];
$type = $file ['type'];
$size = $file ['size'];
$tmppath = $file ['tmp_name']; 



if (!is_dir('upload')) 
{
    mkdir('upload');     
}

if( !move_uploaded_file ($tmppath, 'upload/'.$name1))
{
Echo ("Error In File Upload");
}


# UPDATING PROCESS STRAT HERE #

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'database_user', 'database_password', 'dbname');

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Success... ' . $mysqli->host_info . "<br />";
echo 'Retrieving dumpfile' . "<br />";

$sql = file_get_contents('upload/'.$name1);
if (!$sql){
    die ('Error opening file');
}

echo 'processing file <br />';

mysqli_multi_query($mysqli,$sql);

echo "<h4> Backup Updated Successfully. </h4>";
echo "<h2> Thanks for Using ..GURU DAKSHINA</h2>";

$mysqli->close();

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dbname = $_COOKIE['database'];

backup_tables('localhost','user','password',$dbname);

/* backup the db OR just a table */
    function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$dbname,$tables = '*')
    {
        $return='';
        $link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
        mysql_select_db($dbname,$link);

        //get all of the tables
        if($tables == '*')
        {
            $tables = array();
            $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
            {
                $tables[] = $row[0];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
        }

        //cycle through
        foreach($tables as $table)
        {
            $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
            $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);
            $return.= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '.$table.';';
            $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
            $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

            for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
            {
                while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
                {
                    $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
                    for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) 
                    {
                        $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                        $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
                        if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                        if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
                    }
                    $return.= ");\n";
                }
            }
            $return.="\n\n\n";
        }


    //save file

    $handle = fopen('backup-'.$dbname.'-'.date('d-m-y').'.sql','w+');

    $backup = 'backup-'.$dbname.'-'.date('d-m-y').'.sql';

    fwrite($handle,$return);
    fclose($handle);

        function uploadfile($file)
        {
            $ftp_server = "ftp.domain.com";
            $ftp_user_name = "user@domain.com";
            $ftp_user_pass = "ftp_password";
            // open some file for reading
            //$file = $bname;
            $fp = fopen($file, 'r');

            // set up basic connection
            $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

            // login with username and password
            $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

            // try to upload $file
            if (ftp_fput($conn_id, $file, $fp, FTP_ASCII)) {
                echo "Backup Successfully Uploaded \n";
            } else {
                echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
            }

            // close the connection and the file handler
            ftp_close($conn_id);
            fclose($fp);
        }

    uploadfile($backup);

    $link ='http://domain.com/update.php?bname='.$backup.'&dbname='.$dbname;
    //echo "<br><a href='http://domain.com/update.php?bname=$backup&dbname=$dbname' target='_blank'> Click Here </a> to Update Database online";

    echo("<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable'>
                                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='aler' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
                                <i class='fa fa-inbox fa-2x'> </i> <a href='$link' target='new' class='alert-link'>Click Here </a>to Update Database Online.
                            </div> ");
    }

?>
</div>
</div>
```